# `toBeInstanceOf(Number)` does not work in jest

Tags: jestjs, babel-jest

I have a test as follows:

```
expect(result.data.quota).toBeInstanceOf(Number);
```

This test fails with a weird error saying the a Number was expected and a Number was received:

```
 expect(value).toBeInstanceOf(constructor)

    Expected constructor: Number
    Received constructor: Number
    Received value: 2000
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

> expect(value).not.toBeNaN();

Edit: I would go with @bszoms solution:

```
expect(typeof value).toBe('number')
```

Comment: This is wrong. False is not NaN but also not a number, for example.

Comment: This answer must clearly be avoided. This will make your tests successful for *ANYTHING* but NaN. `false`, `"some string"`, `true`, `Promise`, `ReactComponent` you name it

Answer (score 47):

The following works for all constructors:

```html
expect(value).toEqual(expect.any(Number));
```

Answer (score 24):

You can also do this: `expect(typeof <value>).toBe('number')`

Or you can use [jest-extended](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended), which adds a whole range of matchers including `toBeNumber`.

Both courtesy of the discussion [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3257).

Answer (score 2):

Taking @stephan's anwer, this works for async / promise based methods:

```
await expect(asyncFunction()).resolves.toEqual(expect.any(Number));
```